# How to process a date diference using same id elements in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, counting

**I have the following data structure:**

```
[ (19L, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 12, 3, 43)),
  (19L, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 12, 16, 28, 48)),
  (19L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 11, 58, 19)),
  (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 15, 12, 54, 36)),
  (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 15, 14, 16, 39)),
  (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 8, 58, 39)),
  (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 8, 14, 21, 48)),
  (90L, datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 18, 14, 31)),
  (90L, datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 21, 14, 23)),
  (90L, datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 16, 35, 34))  ]
```

And i need to calculate the average days between the days from users with same id, first element corresponds to user id's and the second one to a datetime.

I'm getting trouble on how to iterate through the list, counting and getting the same diff for each user...

Comment: What's the trouble?

Comment: average visit frequency?

Comment: You can [sort](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), [group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), and average.

Comment: What do you mean by *'calculate the average days'*?

Comment: Will the list always be in order of user id?

Comment: Yes, its group by user id, the second element always will correspond to a purchayse made at a given date. By " average days" i meant the average days between each purchase for each individual user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by user id (assuming the list is sorted by the grouping key - which looks like it is), then, you can use "pairwise" iteration and calculate an average day difference:

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: from operator import itemgetter
In [3]: from itertools import groupby, combinations

In [4]: l = [ 
   ...:   (19L, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 11, 12, 3, 43)),
   ...:   (19L, datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 12, 16, 28, 48)),
   ...:   (19L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 17, 11, 58, 19)),
   ...:   (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 15, 12, 54, 36)),
   ...:   (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 15, 14, 16, 39)),
   ...:   (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 8, 58, 39)),
   ...:   (80L, datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 8, 14, 21, 48)),
   ...:   (90L, datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 18, 14, 31)),
   ...:   (90L, datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 2, 21, 14, 23)),
   ...:   (90L, datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 16, 35, 34))  ]

In [5]: for user_id, dates in groupby(l, itemgetter(0)):
    ...:     dates = [date[1] for date in dates]
    ...:     differences = [abs((d1 - d2).days) for d1, d2 in zip(dates[0::2], dates[1::2])]
    ...:     print(user_id, sum(differences) / len(differences))
    ...:     
(19L, 2)
(80L, 108)
(90L, 1)
```

Comment: I would think the desired output would not be the average difference between all possible combinations, but rather the average difference between successive timestamps

Comment: Exactly, my mistake, sorry.  For the first user the average day distance should be 1 day.

Comment: @MarkF okay, updated the code in the answer - is this what you've meant? Thanks.

Comment: I think you want something more like http://pastebin.com/jB8Bnrig, order the dates and get the difference from the last to the current purchase and average the sums by the total purchases/dates.

Answer (score -1):

I would sort the timestamps into a dictionary where each key is a user's ID and the value is a list of access times. then after sorting that list of timestamps, find the difference between each visit time and find the average. the `datetime.timedelta` object can be used to simplify math operations on timestamps..

```python
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

#l = [(id, datetime), (...), ...]

d = defaultdict(list)
for ID, time in l:
    d[ID].append(time) # build list of times from timestamps
    d[ID].sort() # sorting every time is not optimal but functional

for ID in d.keys():
    timeDeltas = [d[ID][i+1] - d[ID][i] for i in range(len(d[ID])-1)] # create list of timedeltas
    averageVisitFrequency = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, timeDeltas)//len(timeDeltas) # calculate average timedelta
    print 'user {} makes a purchase every {} days on average'.format(ID, averageVisitFrequency.days) # example output usage
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and the code its perfectly understandable. Thank you so much !